# Is verifying a mock interaction a good enough test?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking

I am writing unit tests for some code that uses some third party libraries for calling a web service.

Basically all the code does is route based on some parameters to two or more different web services.

I have mocked these web services and as a test all I can really do is verify they were called with correct parameters. So I am basically just testing the flow control of my code.

Is this the correct way to unit test something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is called unit testing because you are testing small units of your code. A unit test for a particular class should verify that the class behaves correctly, not other parts of the system. There should be other tests for those parts.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes for Unit testing it's better to mock your request/response and run against it. But you may also need a corresponding integration test that hits the live web server for full functional tests. Remember to destroy any footprint of the test on live server though.